# Instruct R to follow a certain sequence when making random forest decision trees

Tags: r, random-forest

I have some data where one of the columns is only relevant after evaluating a different column. For example, when analyzing car data to determine car values, it may be meaningful  to evaluate  whether a Toyota Camry is a Camry LE , and SE, or and XLE. But that is only meaningful after we determine it's a Camry first. If its a Honda, I know that those edition types are irrelevant, or perhaps even worse, counter predictive.  Is there a way for me to help my RF model along by instructing it that certain decisions should always be made before sampling other columns?

I am pretty new to R, so it's taking me some time to reproduce my data. IN Addition, I was advised my mr flick that this should really be posted on the data science stack exchange. Thanks to all.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: And this seems more like a general data modeling question than a specific programming question. If you need help modeling your data, you should ask such questions at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] instead.